# Multi-Stage Stochastic Decomposition

Tags: optimization, binary-variable, stochastic-programming, decomposition, multi-stage

I have a multi-stage model with both binary and continuous first-stage investment variables and continuous operational next-stage variables:

$$
\sum_{s} \rho_{s} \left[ x_{s} + y_{s} + \sum_{t}(y^{op}_{s,t})\right]
$$

With equality and inequality constraints, where a constraint exists that couples the continuous variables indexed t temporally:

$$
y_{t,s} - y_{t-1,s} \le A  
$$

Is there a way to decompose this model by either or both time and scenario? Is there a way to decompose this model by either or both time and scenario?

$\rho$ is the probability constant. $y_{t,s}$ represents the continuous operational variables. $x_s$ and $y_s$ are the binary and continuous investment variables limited by non-anticipative constraints ensuring they hold a single solution for all scenarios.

$$ x_s = x_{\tilde{s}} \ \ \forall s$$
$$ y_s = y_{\tilde{s}} \ \ \forall s$$

Comment: What does $\rho_s()$ look like? Is it linear? Also, are $x$ and $y$ indexed by either time or scenario (or both)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply; I modified my question. $p_s$ is a probability constant; the second stage term is linear, but I am also interested in the case of it being quadratic. $y$ and $x$ are indexed by scenario